# How to make Swing program use the operating system's font?

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I'm making a swing program that uses the OS's look and feel but the font throws the whole thing off.

Comment: What OS? Do you have screenshots of the app. and a native app.?

Comment: My bet is, it's not the font that's throwing it off, it's the lack of appropriate layout managers which are causing you issues